# How to solve $(\ln e)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I know that
$$\ln e^2=2$$
But what about this?
$$(\ln e)^2$$
A calculator gave 1. I'm really confused.

Comment: Note the following things: $\ln(x^2)=2\ln(x)$, $\ln(e)=1$ and $1^2=1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the equality (assuming the operations are actually *defined* for *`m`* and *`n`*):

$$ x =\log _nm$$

What this means is that *`x`* is the number to you need to raise *`n`* to the power of, to get *`m`*. In other words:

$$ n^x = m $$

You probably already *know* this since your question stated:

$$\ln e^2=2$$
and the power you need to raise *`e`* to, to get *`e2`*, is two.

---

In the case where *`n`* and *`m`* are the *same* number, the logarithm will always be one:

$$ x^1 = x, \space \log_xx = 1$$
$$ e^1 = e, \space \log_ee = \ln e = 1$$

And, of course, the reason why you're getting one can be explained with:

$$ (\ln e)^2 = (1)^2 = 1 $$

Answer (score 5):

Since $\ln e = 1 $
So $(\ln e)^2 = 1$

Answer (score 5):

Consider the most important property of logarithm

$$ \log(m)^n = n \log (m) $$

So that, $$ \log_e(e)^2 = 2 \log_e(e) = 2 \ln(e) = 2 $$

And since, $$ [ln(e)^2] ≠ [ln(e)]^2 $$

As you might be thinking that $ ln(e)^2 $ is same as $ [ln(e)]^2 $ but that's not true.

Actually, 
$$ ln(e)^2= ln(e^2) $$

We have $$ [ln(e)]^2 = [1]^2 = 1 $$

Comment: Typesetting note: `$\ln$` is more common to see than `$ln$` and use `\cdot` or `\times` for multiplication (*generally `\cdot` for multiplication of reals for anything about middle-school math and `\times` for very elementary arithmetic, cross products, or cartesian products etc...*).  For more typesetting tips, visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @JMoravitz Done both things!

Answer (score 4):

$\ln e$ is 1. So $(\ln e ) ^ 2 $ is one.

Answer (score 3):

The natural log are the log with base $e$ (*euler's number* our *napier constant*). Therefore
$$ \ln (x) = \log_e(x)$$
When you put $x=e$, we have $\ln(e)$, but that is simply $1$. Therefore $\big(\ln(e)\big)^2=1$.